# TSQL converting varchar to datetime in a nested query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I am running the following query in SQL

```
SELECT TOP 1  
CONVERT(datetime,left(LD_publishdate,10),103) 
AS R   
FROM [patch_stats].[dbo].[vulns]  
ORDER BY R DESC
```

I am getting...

> "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value."

But if I run

```
SET language British
SELECT LD_publishdate 
FROM [patch_stats].[dbo].[vulns]
WHERE ISDATE (LD_publishdate) = 1
```

Then only the correct values are selected.

How can I insert (nest in) the second query into the first one, so only the correct results are converted?

Comment: Please tag the dbms used. (Some product specific SQL there...)

Comment: You've got a query that, on the face of it, is trying to find strings that *aren't* convertible to dates, and you want to nest it within a query that's going to attempt to convert strings to dates?

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop storing dates in strings. You need to store the dates as date to avoid such kind of problem.

You can try to set

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
```

Comment: Time zone and date format are two completely different things.

Comment: More to the point, the OP's explicit specification of `103` *should* already force dates to be interpreted as D/M/Y, should it not?

Comment: I know ... This is a database and a script I inherited from the previous person and I am trying to clean it up \ debug it, actually

Comment: @GeorgeMihailescu:- Can you provide a sample date stored in `LD_publishdate`?

Comment: @rahul-tripathi: If I use SET language British
SELECT LD_publishdate 
FROM [patch_stats].[dbo].[vulns]
WHERE ISDATE (LD_publishdate) = 1, then I get LD_publishdate as 24/11/2014 10:29:36, but if I change it to WHERE ISDATE (LD_publishdate) = 0, then I get LD_publishdate as 6/25/2015 12:00:00 AM which is wrong and I want them to either NOT be taken into account either converted to the 24/11/2014 10:29:36 format

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two queries as:

```
SET language British
SELECT  
CONVERT(datetime,left(LD_publishdate,10),103) 
AS R   
FROM(
SELECT LD_publishdate 
FROM [patch_stats].[dbo].[vulns]
WHERE ISDATE (LD_publishdate) = 1
) T 
ORDER BY R DESC
```

But please note that [ISDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) will return 0 if the expression is a `datetime2` value ( which i think is the case here), but will return 1 if the expression is a valid `datetime` value.

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/ZJPXW97086)</kbd>

Comment: If I am using your nested query I am back to square one, meaning I get the message: "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." Do you know how to get around that?

Comment: Yes.. from what you have described in question it seems `ISDATE (LD_publishdate) = 0` gives you correct dates that you want to convert in format 103 but if that's not the case then you should try as: `ISDATE (LD_publishdate) = 1` in inner query.. else `left(LD_publishdate,10)` is not giving text in desired format..can you plz share a sample result of `left(LD_publishdate,10)` that you want to convert to `datetime`?

Comment: If I use SET language British SELECT LD_publishdate FROM [patch_stats].[dbo].[vulns] WHERE ISDATE (LD_publishdate) = 1, then I get LD_publishdate as 24/11/2014 10:29:36, but if I change it to WHERE ISDATE (LD_publishdate) = 0, then I get LD_publishdate as 6/25/2015 12:00:00 AM which is wrong and I want them to either NOT be taken into account either converted to the 24/11/2014 10:29:36 format

Comment: I am still getting the same "Changed language setting to British.
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
" I must be doing something wrong

Comment: Is there any trigger created on table?

Comment: I just verified now in Object Explorer and there are no triggers or constrains attached to that table